# How can I Select list of list or object of object not like a table? (SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem in SQL Server: I want select list of list or object of object not a table.

Example :

```
SELECT p.Name, List (J.Name), .... 
FROM dbo.Person AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.Jobs AS j ON j.PersonId = p.id
GROUP BY p.name
```

Like a json example :

```
{
   Name : "test"
   Jobs : [
   {
       Name : "Job",
       Position : 2
   },{    
       Name : "Job1",
       Position : 1
   }]
}
```

Is there a solution to this problem for me?

I want to output a stored procedure that I can use for the web service

Comment: hmm.... You're going to have to put more effort into your question. There are whole patterns and frameworks in dot net that do large parts of this. MVC, LINQ, Entity Framework, serialization are just a few places to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person(Id int, Name nvarchar(32));
INSERT dbo.Person VALUES(1, N'test');

CREATE TABLE dbo.Jobs(Id int, Name nvarchar(32), PersonId int, Position int);
INSERT dbo.Jobs VALUES(1, N'Job', 1, 2),(1, N'Job1',1,1);
```

You can just apply `FOR JSON AUTO` to your join to get the results you want (well, close):

```
SELECT p.Name, jobs.Name, jobs.Position
  FROM dbo.Person AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.Jobs AS jobs 
    ON jobs.PersonId = p.id
  FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Output (whitespace mine):

```
{
  "Name":"test",
  "jobs":[
  {
    "Name":"Job",
    "Position":2
  },{
    "Name":"Job1",
    "Position":1
  }]
}
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0fcfaa6091fede1bb883221d6626431f)